# Matrix Block indexing plus mask in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mask

I would like to index a part of a matrix using a logical mask. So as an input I have a Matrix A where there are some `nan` values, I create a `mask` for this using `isnan`. Moreover I have a vector `v` of values that I would like to insert into A `A(mask)=v`. Then I construct another matrix B using A `B=[A;A;A]`. Now I would like to apply the values in `v` to the right position in `B`. How can I do it in Matlab without creating `temp=B(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2))` matrix or to create a new `mask=[mask;false(2*size(A,1),size(A,2))]`?

One more time:

```
A = rand(2,10);
v = A(A>0.5);
A(A>0.5) = nan;
mask = isnan(A);
B=[A;A;A];

% now how to write v to B?
% not doing one of those: 

tmp = B(1:2,:);
tmp(mask) = v;
B(1:2,:) = tmp;

%...

mask1 = [mask;false(4,10)]

mask2 = [false(2,10);mask;false(2,10)]

mask3 = [false(4,10);mask]

B(mask1) = v;
B(mask2) = v;
B(mask3) = v;

% what i miss is something like B(1:2,:)(mask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to fill values at each of the three occurrences of `A` within `B`.

If you don't mind repeating the vector `v`:

```
B = repmat(A.',1,3); % easier to work by columns
B(bsxfun(@plus,find(mask.'),(0:2)*numel(A))) = v(repmat(1:numel(v),1,3)); % fill
B = B.'; % transpose back
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer kind of solves my problem or at least it gives me a good direction to develop. My problem is performance. `B` is a big matrix and the write operation `B(mask)=v` is done very often. Moreover `B`is something like that `B=[A(:,4:end);A(:,3:end-1);A(:,2:end-2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your wording correctly, but if you put these lines at the end:

```
mask2 = repmat(mask, 3, 1);
B(mask2) = NaN
```

It will repeat the NaN values 3 times vertically. It depends on what you mean by 'apply the values in v to the right position in B'

Comment: Thank you, but it solves not what i was trying to ask.